# Read the last (newest) Line from a RichTextBox

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have in my project a RichTextBox; on which i read the flow of a work 
the following code I use for this propose

```
Public Shared Sub FlowBox(ByVal Text As String, ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim FlowText As String = ""
        Dim FlowTextBox As RichTextBox = New RichTextBox
        TableCreation.FlowMonitorRTB.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.DarkBlue
        FlowTextBox = TableCreation.FlowMonitorRTB
        FlowText = Text
        TableCreation.FlowMonitorRTB.Visible = True
        FlowTextBox.Text += FlowText & vbNewLine
        TableCreation.FlowMonitorRTB.Show()
        TableCreation.FlowMonitorRTB.Refresh()
    End Sub
```

All goes well (if I may say that) except that I always read the first line and not the last
What I want is to read the last line every time is written
How can I do that?

I made some changes in my code; which p.campbell advice me

```
Public Shared Sub FlowBox(ByVal Text As String, ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
         With TableCreation.FlowMonitorRTB
            .Text += Text & vbNewLine
            .ForeColor = Drawing.Color.DarkBlue
        End With
    End Sub
```

But still I see the first line in the text sowing in the >FlowBox< and not the last
And something for that one which down voting my question: 
“Before you done anything in your life… thing twice… even so thing once more… Probably you’ll have a misunderstanding”

Comment: The problem is the value you pass as `Text` in the `FlowBox` method? What are you trying to do exactly? What is `TableCreation`? not clear for me.

Comment: This method is inside in a Class and the <FlowBox> is inside in a Form so when I have to write in the RichTextBox I have to refer in the formname.RichTextBox.name

Comment: I don't see where in your code snippet you are *reading* anything from the RTB.  Is TableCreation.FlowMonitorRTB referencing an existing RTB?  It's unclear what purpose FlowTextBox has in this code since it just references the FlowMonitorRTB.

Comment: Wouldn't `Dim line As String = FlowTextBox.Lines(FlowTextBox.Lines.Length - 1)` accomplish this?

Comment: @LarsTech When I say “I’m reading” I mean I show it in my screen. <br/>
>FlowBox< is a RichText on where I’m watching the flow of some certain flow in my code.

Comment: @Tim I put it in my code but nothing happen. I've noticed that while the program is running the main window of the program; and the child window are dead, means I can’t do anything on them (like maximize or what ever can do)

Comment: @LefterisGkinis - Your screen is freezing because the other work is being done on the UI thread.  If you want your screen responsive, you'll need to do that long-running work on another thread (like BackgroundWorker).

Comment: @Tim Please advice my for that... How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that [`FlowTextBox.MultiLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.multiline.aspx) is set to `True`, and that its sizing is appropriate to show more than one line of text.

When you set a breakpoint on this line, does `Text` hold the value that you expect?

```
FlowText = Text
```

Maybe refactor your method a bit to remove some redundancies and provide some clarity?

```
Public Shared Sub FlowBox(ByVal Text As String, ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

   With TableCreation.FlowMonitorRTB
      .Text += Text & vbNewLine
      .ForeColor = Drawing.Color.DarkBlue
      .Visible = True
      .Show()
      .Refresh()
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: See I have already done that. But still I have the same score. I see the first line ONLY while the RichTextBox is fulfilled with lines. When the process stops then I'm able to see all the lines moving the vertical bar.

Comment: Well the professional answer was given by Tim. But the simplest solution was giving it by @p.campbell with a small change in one line.
Instead of:
.Text += Text & vbNewLine
We change it in
.Text = newText & vbNewLine & .text
So always I have the last incoming line at the top of >RichText< area.